# Trying to use pandas to load stock data, but not working

Tags: python, csv, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
#from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import pandas.io.data as web 
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2014,6,2)
end = datetime.datetime(2014,9,25)

google = web.DataReader("GOOG", "yahoo", start, end)
tesla = web.DataReader("TSLA", "yahoo", start, end)
apple = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start, end)
```

This simple code is all that I am trying to run, and I have been able to run it 3 days ago, but for the last 2 days it refuses to run.

The problem: when I set the date to say start=(2014,6,2) end=(2014,8,7) the code will run perfectly fine. However when I change the end date to say (2014,9,15) I will receive the following error:

after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=5&b=2&c=2014&d=8&e=25&f=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv'

I am running all of this using Anaconda(jupyter notebook) so I can only presume the pandas package is up to date and that no changes have occurred.

I also tried to change the outdated import of pandas.io.data with its update pandas_datareader, but the jupyter notebook (using python 3) is not recognizing the modules existence

Any help with why this is happening is Greatly Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me. However, I used pandas_datareader instead of  pandas.io.data as the module has been moved there. I am on pandas 0.19.2

It continued to work after changing `end` as well.

Here's what I did (in IPython) :

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2014, 6, 2)
end = datetime(2014, 9, 5)
google = web.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start, end)
tesla = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
apple = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Comment: Thanks for running this! Now I know the problem is not within the syntax but rather the notebook I'm using since my jupyter notebook refuses to recognize "pandas_datareader"  as a module

Comment: Yep it turns out jupyter notebook does not support that module unless I download the package separately.  Here is the code to put in the terminal for anyone else that runs into this problem! conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda pandas-datareader

Comment: You do need to install pandas-datareader separately in any case. For those not using anaconda, here are typical install commands.  
`sudo -H pip install pandas-datareader` (ubuntu)  or 
`pip install pandas-datareader` (windows)

Comment: @zame If jupyter notebook is not ok. How to run this code then?

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo has switched off the API](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/ichart-stopped-working-2-days-ago/td-p/251515). You can switch to the Google API for a similar service, for example [example link](http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=AAPL&startdate=Jan%2001%2C%202000&output=csv)

Or if using pandas:

```
df = web.DataReader("AAPL", "google", start, end)
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see from other sites using Matlab and Excel that http :// ichart... is not working properly for some people. Try using https :// ichart...  This seems to work for me. Getting today's data using http : // download.finance.yahoo.com still seems to work but it is a little intermittent. 4/18/2017